# Width transform animation without hover ? CSS issue

Tags: css, scroll, width, transform

I come back here looking for your wisdom. I have been working on a website and I did some css to make a width transform animation effect behind some text, and it works fine using hover, buuut I would like to have the same effect only with an automatic animation (with some delay that works with the scroll), but saddly I don't know how.

Any ideas ?

Thanks so much !

here the website:
http://231e47.com/accueil-cf/

The hover effect is on the text "we are here!"

Here my CSS:

```
<style> 
.highlight { display: inline-block; 
color: #343434;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
.highlight::after {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
bottom: 10px;
left: 0%;
transform: translateX(0%);
content: '';
width: 0px;
height: 43%;
background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #48d1de 0%, #84fab0 180%);
transition: all 250ms;
}
.highlight:hover {
color: #343434;
}
.highlight:hover::after {
height: 43%;
width: 108%;
}
</style>
```

THANKS A LOT !

Comment: Sure, thanks for your answer. I did try with an hover effect and I tried to find more info via Google as well, but I didn't find how to link my width transformation into a scrolling automatic animation as I said before. That's why I came here, not to ask for a code but to have at least an idea of the type of subject I could look more into so I can understand the scrolling animation for this kind of width transformation I would like to do. Thanks

Comment: We don't provide "ideas". Scroling is something that requires Javascript so you'd have to research that issue.

Comment: Well that's very rude. If you think you don't provide "ideas" then just ignore my message. I'm here asking for help,  being honest about what I've achieved to do and being honest about telling you that saddly I don't know how to transform a width within a scrolling animation, but I would like to TRY and LEARN. I'm not asking for code, I'm asking just help and "ideas" of what else I could try or look more information about. Just giving me more perspective of trying javascript instead of css that's an excellent help.

Comment: It's not rude to tell you that you're in the wrong place. You dont expect a restaurant to tell you how to fix your car.  that''s why we suggest more **research**.